# triangulation of manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, triangulation

Good evening,

When does a n-manifold have a triangulation?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A manifold with a triangulation is called a piecewise-linear manifold.  To quote wikipedia's article on PL manifolds:

"The obstruction to placing a PL structure on a topological manifold is the [Kirby-Siebenmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirby%E2%80%93Siebenmann_class) class. To be precise, the Kirby-Sibenmann class is the obstruction to placing a PL-structure on $M \times R$ and in dimensions $n$ > 4 this ensures that M has a PL-structure."

This means that a manifold has a triangulation if and only if a particular element of the fourth cohomology group with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients is zero.  It looks like a full description is given in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0105/0105047v1.pdf) on the arxiv.